Leer un archivo de excel en genexus y mostrarlo en un objeto (por ejemplo en un grid)
Queria consultar, resulta que necesito leer un archivo de excel desde genexus 18 y luego los datos que contiene ese archivo de excel mostrarlo en un objeto de genexus (por ejemplo un grid, podria ser otro objeto, lo importante es que pueda mostrar desde genexus los datos del excel).
Para leer los datos del archivo excel codifique el siguiente codigo en un evento asociado a un boton pero al clickear sobre el boton no hace nada:
Event 'Excel'
    &excel.Open("C:\Users\jl\Desktop\dato.xlsx")
    
    if &excel.ErrCode <> 0
        &correcto = false
        &excel.Close() 
    endif
        &Nombre = &excel.Cells(1,2).Text
        &Apellido = &excel.Cells(1,3).Text
        &Edad = &excel.Cells(1,4).Number
    &excel.Show()
Endevent

Por eso solicito su ayuda para ver que mas debo agregar al codigo. Desde ya muchas gracias.
